# How to Calculate the CreatedDate Day of the Week In Process Builder

Tags: formula, process-builder, date

I've been trying to determine in process builder what date of the week the created date is but I keep getting an invalid formula error without details on what is incorrect.

If I try either of the following I receive "The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error".  I'm trying to set a DateTime value.

Note I'd prefer not to use DATEVALUE as I gather this defaults back to GMT and my record could be created anywhere worldwide and it should be based off this.

```
IF(
     OR(MOD(([SM_Problem__c].CreatedDate + 4320/1440) – DATE(1900,1,6), 7) = 0,
           MOD(([SM_Problem__c].CreatedDate + 4320/1440) – DATE(1900,1,6), 7) = 1,
           MOD(([SM_Problem__c].CreatedDate + 4320/1440) – DATE(1900,1,6), 7) = 2),
     [SM_Problem__c].CreatedDate + 7200/1440,
     [SM_Problem__c].CreatedDate + 4320/1440
)


IF(
     OR(MOD(DATEVALUE([SM_Problem__c].CreatedDate + 4320/1440) – DATE(1900,1,6), 7) = 0,
           MOD(DATEVALUE([SM_Problem__c].CreatedDate + 4320/1440)  – DATE(1900,1,6), 7) = 1,
           MOD(DATEVALUE([SM_Problem__c].CreatedDate + 4320/1440)  – DATE(1900,1,6), 7) = 2),
     [SM_Problem__c].CreatedDate + 7200/1440,
     [SM_Problem__c].CreatedDate + 4320/1440
)

Note, no errors occur in a non Process Builder formula field if I try

IF(
     OR(MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate + 4320/1440) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7) = 0,
        MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate + 4320/1440) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7) = 1,
        MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate + 4320/1440) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7) = 2),
     (CreatedDate + 7200/1440),
     (CreatedDate + 4320/1440)
)
```

Any tips on what I can do for this in my process builder field would be appreciated. Basically I want to set an end date and need to determine if I should add weekend hours or not. I want to find out if in 72 hours time that the date will be in a weekend or not.